# Crystal Reports. How do I show amount of records between 2 optional dates

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm new to Crystal and I have to create a basic report that requires 2 input optional parameters: `DateStart` and `DateEnd`. 
Report shall include amount of records in a table beetween 2 dates (if `DateEnd` date value is missed report shall consider that it requires all records no matter how old they are. If `DateStart` is missed report shall consider it requires all records no matter how young they are)

I guess I'll have to use `SQL Expression Field` but can't figure out how to implement where clause.

How would you implement such a report?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 1. You can not pass your parameters into SQL Expression Fields 2. Do i understand you correctly: if you omit DateEnd then you want all records in the table **or** all records older than DateStart?

Comment: @Roberts, that's correct

Comment: What language are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create a `Date Parameter` with `optional prompt` and `range`.

Then i Record Selection Formula put:

```
if ( (not HasValue({?PARAM_YOUR_DATE}) or (not(HasLowerBound({?PARAM_YOUR_DATE}))) or (not(HasUpperBound({?PARAM_YOUR_DATE}))) ) then
  True
else
  {YOURDB.YOUR_DATE_FIELD} in {?PARAM_YOUR_DATE};
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to show all records add special value i.e. 01/01/1900

```
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value ="19000101";
```

In First Formula

```
{?DateStart} = '19000101' or {table.DateStart} = {?DateStart}
```

In Second Formula

```
{?DateEnd} = '19000101' or {table.DateEnd} = {?DateEnd}
```

no need to use if else statement.